# Wireshark not capturing HTTPS packets?

Tags: https, wireshark, packet-capture

Wireshark is not capturing https packets. I've tried filtering them by `portmap.port == 443` but no https packet is shown, however, http packets are captured fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to filter for `port 443` that should work. Your filter does something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`portmap` refers to the [ONC RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) [portmapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap) protocol.  That's only used for ONC RPC protocols such as NFS, YP, and the portmapper/rpcbind protocol itself.

HTTP, and HTTP-over-SSL/TLS, i.e. "https", do *not* use ONC RPC and, in particular, don't use the portmapper.  They run atop TCP, so you'd want a display filter such as `tcp.port == 443`.  (If you want a *capture* filter, so the only traffic you capture is traffic to or from port 443, `port 443` would be the equivalent capture filter.)